# .htaccess SSL certificate for manually added subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, subdomain

I have got my .htaccess file working for my main domain (www.domain.com):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However, for my Subdomain www.domain.com/subdomain/ the icon starts as a secure padlock but then goes to unsecure. I am using this in the .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any ideas on what I should put in the subdomain file?

Comment: Between `www.domain.com` and `www.domain.com/subdomain/`, you would not be switching between different domains to begin with - that is the same domain, so the certificate should apply for both the same, and without problem. And you don’t appear to be talking about `subdomain.domain.com` here, which would then internally get rewritten to that folder, either. Have you first of all checked the browser console? This is probably rather an issue of “mixed content” to begin with.

Comment: I fixed the issue, I had an image using another domain, once I removed this my site was secure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out, there was an image using an external URL.